# CQLSH :Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'XX.XX.XX.XXX': OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

As part of my testing i have created around 2000 column families in cassandra database and started facing below issue.

Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'IP_ADDRESS': OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None',)})

As we know cassandra has a limitation in creating number of column families. I would like to know how to resolve above issue and what will be the maximum allowed number in creating column families.

Comment: It's true that c* isn't built to hanlde thousands of tables. But your issue seems unrelated. Is your node up?

Comment: Yes , my entire cluster is up.

Comment: [datastax@ 00:07:24]:~> nodetool status
Datacenter: Analytics
=====================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN    IP 16.79 GB   1       ?       4448306f-551b-4165-85dc-161b14eca2de  rack1
UN   IP  17.09 GB   1       ?       2a672762-4887-4d74-bb5e-5a60217be89d  rack1

Comment: check whether port (default 9160) is opened from the system you are trying to connect to you cluster.

Comment: Your status output looks weird, unless you are deliberately obscuring the IP addresses they should appear in the 2nd column where you show values like 16.79 and 17.09.

Answer (score 4):

Setting control_connection_timeout=10.0 fixes this problem for me:

```
class CassandraLib(object):
    def __init__(self, server, database, user, password):
        if not isinstance(server, list):
            server = [server]
        auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=user, password=password)
        self.cluster = Cluster(server, auth_provider=auth_provider,
                               protocol_version=3, connect_timeout=30,
                               control_connection_timeout=10.0)
        self.database = database
        self.session = None
```